# Display date of a given weekday based on CalendarWeek

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-formula, powerapps-canvas

I am working on a power app that would be somekind of a weekly  TimeSheet, let`s say.

Each row is a project and each column is a day/date from the week.
The user will be able to choose a calendar week.
Based on the chosen calendar week each column should change it`s header to the dates in this week.
e.g If CW 1 2020 => First column should change to 30.12.2019, second column to 31.12.2019, etc.

Basically what I need is formula that will get the CW and the weekday num (e.g CW 1, weekday 1) and calculate the date.

Thank you!

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow!  Would you mind editing your post and showing us what you've attempted so far?

Answer (score 1):

Week Number

```
RoundDown((RoundUp(selec.SelectedDate-Date(Year(selec.SelectedDate-Weekday(selec.SelectedDate-1)+4);1;3);0)+
Weekday(Date(Year(selec.SelectedDate-Weekday(selec.SelectedDate-1)+4);1;3))+5)
/7;0)
```

Weekday

```
Weekday( Now() )
```